# 400 Bad Request - Facebook Graph API - HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, winforms, facebook-graph-api, httpwebrequest

Every time I run the following code I get an exception:

**Code**

```
 Dim url As String = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_sourceData.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString) & "&type=event&limit=5000"
 Dim getFullURL As String = (url & Convert.ToString("&access_token=")) + _appToken
 Dim stream As New StreamReader(HttpWebRequest.Create(getFullURL).GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
 Dim output As String = stream.ReadToEnd()
 stream.Close()
```

**Exception:**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

My first thought was that it could be an execution limit Facebook has in place over each of their API access tokens; however, if I copy the contents of the 'getFullURL' string variable during runtime and paste it directly into my internet browser, it works fine. Given that it works to copy-paste into web browser, I'm very stuck on how to continue troubleshooting!

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was related to me hitting the maximum API calls (200/hr). I had an erroneous loop that kept repeating the API call during my testing that made me hit this limit.